# Is it good to use a big set or a equivalent map with sets in it?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have some data points collected from different companies identified by companyId, and the name property of each data point could be duplicate in one company or among different companies.The problem is to group all the data points by its name property which belong to different companies, which means we ignore the data point if its company has already existed in the group.

For example the data points are:

companyId     data-point name
1---------------------A
1---------------------A
1---------------------B
2---------------------A
3---------------------B

The results would be:

data-point name           group

A=================(1,A)(2,A)
B=================(1,B)(2,B)

We can see that the second data point A from company 1 was ignored.

There are two ways as far as i know to do deduplicate work.
1.Build a `Map<String(data point name), Set<Long(companyId)>>`

```
Map<String, Set<Long>> dedup = new HashMap<>();
for(DataPoint dp : datapoints){
    String key = dp.getName();
    if(!dedup.contains(key)){
        dedup.put(key, new HashSet<Long>());
    }
    if(dedup.get(key).contains(dp.getCompanyId()){
        continue;
    }
    dedup.get(key).add(dp.getCompanyId());
}
```

2.Build a Big `Set<String>`

```
Set<String> dedup;
for(DataPoint dp : datapoints){
    String key = dp.getName() + dp.getCompanyId();
    if(dedup.contains(key)){
        continue;
    }
    dedup.add(key);
}
```

So which one is better or more appropriate ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do exactly. You have a list of data points and want to group it by the company they belong to? Why do you group by name, and not by company, ie `Map<Company, DataPoint>`?

Comment: That depends on what your exact goal is. Is it to read and process that data (in one shot), or are we talking about all kinds of different queries or dynamic adding / removal of entries? What are your use cases?

Comment: General observation about (2) is that changing the loop body to simply `dedup.add(dp.getName() + dp.getCompanyId());` would be equivalent and faster.

Comment: Similar observation about (1): you don't need to use `contains` before `add`: a `Set` does that for you.

Comment: in one shot @GhostCat

Comment: it is @AndyTurner

Comment: @L.Maple it is what?

Comment: as you have said, there is no need to use contains. @AndyTurner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method (1) is way better, because method 2 kind of destroys the type information.

There are ready-made collections already available for such cases if you want a well-tested robust implementation, with many additional features.

Guava: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html

Eclipse collections:
https://www.eclipse.org/collections/

If you just want a simple implementation, you can follow your method (1) and do it yourself.

Result would be something like this:

```
{
   "A": [1, 2],
   "B": [1, 2]
}
```

Few reasons why I don't prefer method 2:

1. The method is not reliable. If company name ends with a number, then you might have false deduplication. So, you may need to add a special character like so: `<id>~<name>`
2. If you need to consider one more parameter later, it becomes more messy. You may have to do `<id>~<name>~<pincode>` etc.,
3. In method 1, you have the added convenience that you can put the company bean directly, if you implement a hashcode and equals which are based on the companyId field alone

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do (1) would be:

```
Map<String, Set<Long>> dedup =
    datapoints.stream().collect(
        groupingBy(
            DataPoint::getName,
            mapping(DataPoint::getCompanyId, toSet()));
```

The easiest way to do (2) would be:

```
Set<String> dedup =
    datapoints.stream()
        .map(d -> d.getName() + d.getCompanyId())
        .collect(toSet());
```

The one you choose depends upon what you're trying to do, since they yield different types of data, as well as potentially different results.

Comment: If you keep up that reputation pace in 2019 just every day, you will get to 100 K easily. 2k per month is quite realistic :-)